# Bug presents itself in testing but not in eclipse even though eclipse is set to use the same version if JAVA?

Tags: java, eclipse

I ran into an old bug in 1.6 related to generics, i've fixed this by updating java however the bug did not present itself on my local machine when running the code in eclipse despite eclipse being set to use the same version of java as the testing environment. i would like to know how this could be? (bug is present when running java from terminal or testing environment)

what is different when running code from within eclipse?

we have tested this on two PC's

Comment: I got to know somewhere it is running and somewhere not, but confused after reading complete question, where it is running and where not. Please explain.

Comment: Eclipse uses JDT as internal compiler for incremental compiling, highlighting, etc. But I think for actually running the program it still uses the compiler of the specified JDK. If it doesn't this would be an explanation.